# Twilio integration: How to play audio while forwarding a call to a number

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-php

I've integrated twilio with a application i am coding, everything works great. 
i read almost all of the documentation but i cannot find a way to play an 
audio while forwarding a call. i can play it before forwarding the call but i 
would like to play the audio while the phone is ringing. anyone has a 
solution?

```
 <Play loop="<?php echo $loop_audio_track; ?>"><?php echo $audio_track ?> 
 </Play>

 <Say voice="<?php echo $voice; ?>" language="<?php echo $language_code; ?
>"><?php echo $busy_message ?></Say>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think for this to work is to use a conference room to connect the two parties.

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <ConferencewaitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical&amp;Message=please%20wait">
    1000
    </Conference>
  </Dial>
```

Maybe one of the twilio evegalists on here will have a better suggestion

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  This is what I would have suggested.